# Is "imbedded" a valid spelling of the word "embedded"?

Tags: orthography, vowels, is-it-a-word

I have seen this used on our marketing materials:

> The technology imbedded in this solution will help improve productivity.

I was going to flag it as a spelling error, however Googling provided some references to it being a proper usage.

My instinct is that it is wrong however, can anyone shed any light?

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Imbedded

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regarding Oxford Dictionaries, yes it is:

> **[embed](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/embed?region=us&q=imbed)**
>
> Pronunciation:
>    /emˈbed/
>
> (also **imbed** /im-/)

Comment: Does this say it is a valid spelling, or just a valid pronunciation?

Comment: @leonigmig I'm sorry, actually there must be a line break which makes is more clear. I added it, but following the link it is more obvious. The *imbed* does not refer to the pronunciation but to an alternative spelling for *embed*.

Comment: @leonigmig: The notation implies both.  Had it only been a variant pronunciation, it would read: "**embed** /emˈbed/ (*also* /im-/)".  With both the variant spelling _and_ pronunciation, it shows there's a variant spelling, and another pronunciation. See, e.g.: [scallop](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scallop) (1 way to spell, 2 to pronounce); [embed](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/embed) (2 ways to spell and pronounce); and [judgement](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/judgement) (2 ways to spell; 1 way to pronounce).

Answer (score 4):

This is general reference, ***provided*** you have access to a ***good*** dictionary. The problem is that the free online ones often aren’t very good.

These days, *imbed* is commonly perceived to be a misspelling of *embed* perpetrated by victims of **the *pin–pen* merger**.

However, the OED2 (1989) lists *imbed* as [an alternate spelling of *embed*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/60835), while pointing out that *embed* is now the more common form.

Comment: The pin-pen merger is not related; people that don't exhibit the merger [often don't firmly distinguish them in unstressed positions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_reduction).

Comment: Is this the place to mention there's an Agatha Christie "Miss Marple" mystery that hinges on this point?