# Is "pidgeon" a correct alternate spelling of "pigeon"?

Tags: orthography, is-it-a-word

Is "pidgeon" a correct spelling for the grayish fowl scientifically known as Columba livia domestica? Pigeon appears to be the more common spelling, but it looks strange to me.

For comparison, words such as bludgeon, bridge, and midget use the "dg" construct, and words like belligerent and indigenous do not. I supply the following Ngram to save time for anyone who may need to refer to it.

[image]

Additionally, can one predict which way a word with the "idge" sound will be spelled, or is this a case-by-case kind of thing?

Comment: I think it's General Reference that ***pigeon*** is the "correct" spelling. OED actually lists ***pidgeon*** as one of the alternate spellings, because it has been used in the past. It's really just a matter of opinion whether one would take that to mean it's still a "valid" spelling today, but frankly I doubt many people would.

Comment: Sorry if my comment was confusing. I'd noticed your rep was 101, implying you're an established user somewhere on SE. But I suppose not all SE sites have General Reference as a possible closevote reason, so it might not be obvious to you that the primary purpose of my comment was to *explain why* I had just closevoted. The general principle on ELU is that since there *is* no "final authority" on what constitutes a "valid word", many of us don't generally approve of such questions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. Your explanation made it much clearer. Now I would like to ask, why is "Spelling and punctuation" listed as on-topic in this site's [Help and Welcome Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if questions about spelling, such as this one, are not actually on topic? Can you provide an example of a spelling question that *is* on topic and explain how I strayed from the example, so that I may ask better questions in the future?

Comment: I may not be able to help you much on those points. Bear in mind I'm only one voice here, and others may not agree with my position. Note that the full OED list includes *pegen, pegeon, pegeone, pegion, pegon, peion, peioun, peiun, pejon, pejone, pejoun, pichon, pychon, pygeoun, pygyne, pyion, pyione, pyioun, pyjon, pigon, pegyon, pygeon, pigion, pigeon, pegyn, pichion, pidgin, pigen, pigin, pydgyn, pyggion, pygion, pygon, pygyn, piggen, pidgeon, pidgion, pigeing, piggion, pydgion, pudgen, pigioun, powdȝon, pudȝeoun, pudyean, pigeon...*

Comment: ...but it's worth noting *pidgeon* is qualified as *(now irreg.)*. There might be something interesting in the matter of *why* this particular word has so many variants, but any "simpler" dictionary (or just your own NGram research) will easily establish the current preferred version. Personally, I think [this "spelling" question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67343/) is a better one, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: If you look up *pidgeon*, you will usually see it listed as an alternate spelling, or online see this: *Pigeon (disambiguation) Pigeon is a common name for birds of the taxonomic family Columbidae, or a common name for the Rock Pigeon.* or "*archaic for pigeon*".

Comment: @Rusher: I put the words "correct" and "valid" in quotes to indicate that these are highly subjective terms, and by the very nature of your question it's almost certain you and I have a very different understanding of what they might mean in this particular context. The standard spelling of *pigeon* is GR, and the precise status of all variants is subjective, Primarily Opinion-based, and thus Off Topic. The *embed/imbed* example I linked to is a little more complicated, so I would say it's (just about) ***On** Topic*.

Comment: To repeat my earlier point, I'm not a mod, so I don't speak ***for*** ELU. Particularly in this specific context, where I was just the third of five users who closevoted. It just so happens I was the first to post a comment *explaining* my closevote - but no-one has upvoted any of my comments, so it's not necessarily obvious what any other users think of your points. I suggest you may get a better feel for the overall position if you raise the issue on [ELU Meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: That edit doesn't really change *my* position, because the question still seems to me to turn on what exactly "correct" means. @Medica's comment notwithstanding, I've just checked the first four dictionary entries found by Googling "define pigeon", and not *one* of them mentions the ***pidgeon*** spelling. Conversely, all the first four entries for *embed* mention ***imbed***, which I think makes it somewhat more reasonable to ask here how "acceptable" the alternative is (it's still *subjective*, but not quite so *obvious*).

Comment: I await your *next* question with some interest. Bear in mind that so far as On/Off Topic is concerned, the Help Pages are only really *guidelines*. And some of us (myself included) are quite prepared to ignore them if we think otherwise. I realise you probably don't think I'm being particularly helpful in these comments, but please don't forget that there are plenty more users (many wiser than me) who will be happy to address (and hopefully *satisfy*) your concerns on Meta.

Answer (score -3):

'Pidgeon' is both slang and a word:

*BLUE PIDGEON FLIERS, thieves who steal lead off
houses and churches, (cant).*

*MILK THE PIDGEON, to endeavour at impossibilities.*

The **Pidgeon process** used in metallurgy.

The term 'Pidgeon' is not in: LIST SPECIMENS OF BIRDS THE COLLECTION BRITISH MUSEUM.
By G. R. GRAY, F.L.S. &c. PART;rV.>:; PRINTED BY ORDER OF THE TRUSTEES. LONDON: 1856

This [etymological site](http://surnames.enacademic.com/36774/Pidgeon) suggests the term 'Pidgeon''s etymology is unclear but Wikipedia states "Pidgeon is a surname from an archaic spelling of pigeon".

The term **Ring-Dove**, or a Wood-Pidgeon (Dictionarium Britannicum,Bailey, N. (Nathan), d. 1742) suggests that the pidgeon was the West and East African RingDove or ***Streptopelia decipiens***. -Wild pigeons and doves. . Delacour, Jean, 1890-1985. Your aforementioned ***Columba livia domestica*** was derived from the Rock Pigeon

Comment: The administrators can change the color for links or you could develop protanopia to make your life easier ;-)